# AJAX POST Success div upload disappears after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am having issue after a successful AJAX post, where the updated div disappears after a few moments

Below are the jquery/PHP/POST data in succession.

Button On Click Function:

```
function Delete_ID(clickBtnValue,clickBtnID,clickBtnName) {
  var my_data = {"passvalue": clickBtnValue, "passid":clickBtnID, "passname":clickBtnName};
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../Programs/Programs.php',
    data: my_data,
    success: function (data) {
      $('#ProgramsTable').load("../Programs/ProgramChange.php");
      $('#update-div').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

PHP DIV display:

```
$list_programs = DB_Get_Program_List();
if (!is_null($list_programs)) {
  $html = '<br><div id="ProgramsTable"><div class="TABLE">';
  for ($ii=0; $ii < count($list_programs); $ii++) {
    $html .= <<<HTML
    <div class="CELL">
      <form method="post" action>{$list_programs[$ii]["Program_Name"]}
        <button onclick="Delete_ID('Delete','{$list_programs[$ii]["Name_Hash"]}', '{$list_programs[$ii]["Program_Name"]}')" class="button">Delete</button>
        <button onclick="Delete_ID('Edit','{$list_programs[$ii]["Name_Hash"]}', '{$list_programs[$ii]["Program_Name"]}')" class="button">Edit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    HTML;
  }
}
echo $html;
echo "</div></div><div id='update-div'></div>";
```

POST in Programs.php:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if ($_POST['passvalue'] == "Delete"){
      DB_Delete_Program_list($_POST['passid']);
      echo $_POST['passname'] . " has been deleted";
    }
    if ($_POST['passvalue'] == "Edit"){
      echo '  <div class="form_div"><form class="Edit_form" method="post">';
      echo '     <div style="margin-top:5px"><input type="text" style="height:20px;" id="'.$_POST['passid'].'" value="'.$_POST['passname'].'" size="40" maxlength="253"></div>';
      echo '    <div style="margin-top:10px"></div>';
      echo '    <div ><input class="form_submit" type="Submit" name="Edit_button"></div>';
      echo '  </form></div>';
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I press delete, it will display for example "Program 1 has been deleted" and then disappear
When I press edit, the new form table and display and then disappear

[Here is a screen record of my issue](https://youtu.be/QW2jGuFemIY)

What do I need to change, to make it so my div data "table" refreshes with the latest SQL data while also keeping the success text message?

**DSICLAIMER**
Yes I am aware that the EDIT POST option is not how it's supposed to be, as I am just testing the success message return.
Yes there is SQL mitigation in place

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening is when you click your button, you're submitting the form while also triggering your `Delete_ID` function. So, what happens is the JS function executes and displays your div, but the page also reloads, so you only see it for a moment. What you need to do is to call `preventDefault()` on the `event` that is generated by the `onclick` event.

As a tangent, to make passing the data to your `Delete_ID` function easier, I'd recommend using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) rather than passing the data as properties to the function itself.

This is how I'd redo your code.

For your form buttons, remove the `onclick` attribute, and use the `data-` attributes for relevant properties. I also added `delete-button` and `edit-button` classes to each button to distinguish them.

```php
$list_programs = DB_Get_Program_List();
if (!is_null($list_programs)) {
  $html = '<br><div id="ProgramsTable"><div class="TABLE">';
  for ($ii=0; $ii < count($list_programs); $ii++) {
    $html .= <<<HTML
    <div class="CELL">
      <form method="post" action>{$list_programs[$ii]["Program_Name"]}
        <button data-name-hash="{$list_programs[$ii]["Name_Hash"]}"  data-program-name="{$list_programs[$ii]["Program_Name"]}" class="button delete-button">Delete</button>
        <button data-name-hash="{$list_programs[$ii]["Name_Hash"]}"  data-program-name="{$list_programs[$ii]["Program_Name"]}" class="button edit-button">Edit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    HTML;
  }
}
echo $html;
echo "</div></div><div id='update-div'></div>";
```

Then in your javascript, assign the on-click function to buttons with the matching class. This allows you to access the click `event` in that function.

```js
$('.delete-button').click(Delete_ID);
```

Now, update the function definition to use the click `event` and pull the data from data attributes:

```js
function Delete_ID(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from submitting so the page doesn't reload

  const clickedBtn = event.target; // This is a reference to the <button> itself. 

  const clickBtnValue = 'Delete'; // You could pass this via data attributes too; I assume you'll probably have a separate Edit_ID function though. 

  // Pull the values from the `data-` attributes on the clicked button
  // Note that JS converts the kebab-case attribute names (eg: data-name-hash) to camelCase with "data" removed (eg: nameHash). 
  const clickBtnID = clickedBtn.dataset.nameHash;
  const clickBtnName = clickedBtn.dataset.programName;

  var my_data = {"passvalue": clickBtnValue, "passid":clickBtnID, "passname":clickBtnName};
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../Programs/Programs.php',
    data: my_data,
    success: function (data) {
      $('#ProgramsTable').load("../Programs/ProgramChange.php");
      $('#update-div').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

[Here's a very basic JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/5erzqup9/) of using `preventDefault` with data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to prevent your form to be submitted when you press Delete/Edit button, you can do it by remove form tag

```
$list_programs = DB_Get_Program_List();
if (!is_null($list_programs)) {
    $html = '<br><div id="ProgramsTable"><div class="TABLE">';
    for ($ii=0; $ii < count($list_programs); $ii++) {
        $html .= <<<HTML
            <div class="CELL">
                {$list_programs[$ii]["Program_Name"]}
                <button onclick="Delete_ID('Delete','{$list_programs[$ii]["Name_Hash"]}', '{$list_programs[$ii]["Program_Name"]}')" class="button">Delete</button>
                <button onclick="Delete_ID('Edit','{$list_programs[$ii]["Name_Hash"]}', '{$list_programs[$ii]["Program_Name"]}')" class="button">Edit</button>
            </div>
        HTML;
    }
}

echo $html;
echo "</div></div><div id='update-div'></div>";
```

or return false on button click event

```
$list_programs = DB_Get_Program_List();
if (!is_null($list_programs)) {
    $html = '<br><div id="ProgramsTable"><div class="TABLE">';
    for ($ii=0; $ii < count($list_programs); $ii++) {
        $html .= <<<HTML
            <div class="CELL">
                <form method="post" action>{$list_programs[$ii]["Program_Name"]}
                    <button onclick="Delete_ID('Delete','{$list_programs[$ii]["Name_Hash"]}', '{$list_programs[$ii]["Program_Name"]}'); return !1" class="button">Delete</button>
                    <button onclick="Delete_ID('Edit','{$list_programs[$ii]["Name_Hash"]}', '{$list_programs[$ii]["Program_Name"]}'); return !1" class="button">Edit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        HTML;
    }
}

echo $html;
echo "</div></div><div id='update-div'></div>";
```